# friendly URL to open member page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Working in asp.net, in VB I want a site visitor to be able to see a Member's page by going to i.e. `almosbarn.com/tom`. I need to extract the "tom" part, look it up in the database, then open tom's webpage. The lookup, database, and view page parts work. My problem is I've tried setting it up in the `global.asax` `application_start` to get the "tom" segment but I get the error `"request is not available in this context"`. My code to capture it in the `global.aspx` `application_start` is:

```
Dim vMbrID = Httpcontext.Current.Request.URL.Segments.Last()
```

This works and gives me "tom" on a test page, but not the `global.aspx` page, where I get the error.

Comment: Google for Url rewrite. But I bet you probably will have to include some clue in the url to distinguish members page from standard pages (http://server.com/m/userid) for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application_Start` event is fired when an `HttpApplication` instance is first created. At this point, the request information is not available; there might not even *be* a request in progress.

You want your code to fire at the start of a request, so move it to [the `Application_BeginRequest` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx).

Comment: +1 - Yes Application_BeginRequest is the one you are after. You can inspect the URI for every request and route them on from there..

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set up routing in your global.asax to let you handle these kinds of situations.

[MSDN on routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

[MSDN walkthrough on routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX)